# Hide UILabel background color and restore it when needed

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uilabel, uibackgroundcolor

I want to make the same effect like `UITableViewCell` does when `UITableViewCell` is selected or highlighted.
I want manually hide background color of `UILabel` and restore it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UILabel`, override `setHighlighted:` and change the background color of the label according to the value passed to the method.